# OpenCV fps reduced when video resized

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame-rate

I am trying to process recorded videos for feature point recognition. When I process the video at it's full resolution (1280*720) the video playback is slower than it should be. Whenever I reduce the resolution down to 640*360 the fps drops dramatically. What would be the cause of this?

```
  if(captureOpen == false){
    img_scene = cvCaptureFromFile("20151115_154042_582.mp4");
  }
  while(1) {
    image = cvQueryFrame(img_scene);
    if(image.empty()) {
      cout << "IMAGE EMPTY" << endl;
      continue;
    }
    else {
      frameCount++;
    }
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    captureOpen = true;
    processingThread(gray, imageIndex);
    myfile << cvGetCaptureProperty(img_scene, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) << endl;
    imshow("Output", gray);
    key = cvWaitKey(5);
```

I've tried reducing `cvWaitKey();` to `1` but it doesn't seem to have any noticeable effect on fps, I've also tried removing the gray scale conversion but that does not have a noticeable effect either.

(I've tried both handbrake and ffmpeg to reduce the resolution)

Comment: Try to debug using chrono (like in this [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)) to figure out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Without knowing what is in your processing thread it's hard to say. That said, I do know from some experience with openCV that converting to grayscale takes a decent amount of time and when you drop the resolution as well all these operations do take a decent amount of time. I would suggest like the guy above said and find what exactly is eating up all your time. From there we can probably help more.

Comment: I've tried processing it without converting it to gray scale and it's just as bad.